# Understanding the concept of "Viable Prefixes"

Tags: compilers, parsers

I was going through the text: *Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools* by *Ullman et. al* where I came across the concept of viable prefix and I faced some difficultly in grasping the concept. So I present my doubts here in a systematic manner, with a hope for clarification.

---

> Viable Prefixes: The set of prefixes of right sentential forms that can appear on the stack of a shift-reduce parser are called viable prefixes.

This is the actual definition. No problem with it, since it is a definition after all.

---

> An equivalent definition of a viable prefix is that it is a prefix of a right-sentential form that does not continue past the right end of ***the rightmost handle of that sentential form.***

I do not quite understand why ***"the rightmost handle"***? And why not ***the leftmost handle***?

Is it so because of grammars like:

[image: Grammar]

can have the two possible rightmost derivations for $id_1+id_2*id_3$:

[image: Derivation 1] *Derivation (1)*

[image] *Derivation (2)*

where for the right sentential form $E+E*id_3$ there are two handles:

left: $\require{color}\colorbox{pink}{E+E}*id_3$ and

right: $E+E*\require{color}\colorbox{pink}{$id_3$}$

---

> By this definition, it is always possible to add terminal symbols to the end of a viable prefix to obtain a right-sentential form.

Is it something like this, Suppose

$$(1) S \xrightarrow [\text{rm}]{\text{*}} ABCDE \xrightarrow[\text{rm}]{\text{*}} ABpqr$$

$$(2) S \xrightarrow [\text{rm}]{\text{*}} ABCDE \xrightarrow[\text{rm}]{\text{*}} ABxyz$$

So adding terminals $pqr$ or $xyz$ to the viable prefix $AB$ we can get a right sentential form...

---

> Therefore, there is apparently no error as long as the portion of the input seen to a given point can be reduced to a viable prefix.

This I feel from the actual definition is true, because a viable prefix is a prefix appearing on the stack...

---

Is my understanding fine? If not please rectify me.